# Using locale in the $resource URL

Tags: angularjs, locale, ngresource

My AngularJS application is getting server data from a rails JSON API and the API routes are localized, for example:

```
/:locale/api/categories/
```

I am trying to define a `$resource` that would enable the localization. So far, I've been unsuccessful (see the approaches I've tried below).

---

**First attempt**

```
$resource('/:localeId/api/categories/:categoryId', {
    localeId: $locale.id,
    categoryId: "@id",
    format: 'json'
})
```

This does not work. The `localeId` is only evaluated once, when the `$resource` is created.

**Second attempt**

```
$resource('/:localeId/api/categories/:categoryId', {
    localeId: "$locale.id",
    categoryId: "@id",
    format: 'json'
})
```

This does not work either, the generated URL is `/$locale.id/api/categories/`.

**Third attempt**

```
$resource('/:localeId/api/categories/:categoryId', {
    localeId: "@localeId",
    categoryId: "@id",
    format: 'json'
})
```

This works but obliges me to define `localeId` everytime I use my `$resource`.

---

Is there a better way to automatically use `$locale.id` inside my `$resource` URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just provide a function that returns your value ([see documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/docs/api/ngResource/service/$resource)):

```
$resource('/:localeId/...', {
    localeId: function () {
        return $locale.id;
    },
    // ...
})
```